# D3 Pie chart not showing legend

Tags: angular, d3.js, pie-chart

Legend is created in the `g` tag. How can I pull it out side like this example.
with color bar on right hand side.

[image]

**Code**

```
    this.svg = d3.select("#airlineChart").select("svg");
     this.mainContainer = this.svg
          .append("g")
          .attr("transform", `translate(${this.radius},${this.radius})`)

;
    private drawSlices() {
    this.slices = this.mainContainer
      .selectAll("path")
      .remove()
      .exit()
      .data(this.pie(this.pieairline))
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .append("path")
      .attr("d", this.arc);

    this.slices
      .append("rect") // make a matching color rect
      .attr("class", "pieLegend")
      .attr("width", 10)
      .attr("height", 10)
      .append("text") // add the text
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.data.name;
      })
      .style("font-size", 12)
      .attr("y", 10)
      .attr("x", 11);


    this.slices
      .attr("fill", (d, i) => this.color(i))
      .attr("stroke", "black")
      .style("stroke-width", "0px");
      }
```

`slice` is just plan variable with any `datatype`

**current view**

[image]

**console**

[image]

Comment: We need some more code. Can you show us, where `this.slices` is defined?

Comment: @Sirko, question updated.

Answer (score 0):

The element returned from a method-chain in `d3` is usually the last element you create in that chain. So the following will give you a reference to the created `<path>`-elements:

```
this.slices = this.mainContainer
  .selectAll("path")
  .remove()
  .exit()
  .data(this.pie(this.pieairline))
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", this.arc);
```

In the next call you then append further `<rect>` and `<text>` elements to this `<path>`, assigning child nodes to its DOM-representation.

The quick fix would be to append all elements directly under the corresponding `<g>`-element:

```
this.slices = this.mainContainer
  .selectAll("path")
  .remove()
  .exit()
  .data(this.pie(this.pieairline))
  .enter()
  .append("g")

// append the circle segment
this.slices
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", this.arc)
  .attr("fill", (d, i) => this.color(i))
  .attr("stroke", "black")
  .style("stroke-width", "0px");

// append the rect element
this.slices
  .append("rect") // make a matching color rect
  .attr("class", "pieLegend")
  .attr("width", 10)
  .attr("height", 10)
  .attr("fill", (d, i) => this.color(i))
  .attr("stroke", "black")
  .style("stroke-width", "0px");

// append the text element
this.slices
  .append("text") // add the text
  .text((d) => d.data.name )
  .style("font-size", 12)
  .attr("y", 10)
  .attr("x", 11);
```

Sidenote: I think you should add the legend into a different container element. This makes moving it around using `transform()` much easier then splitting it over many `<g>`-elements. To do that basically you need to bind your data to a second set of elements (in the same way you already did). This second set then only contains the `<rect>` and `<text>` elements, but not the circle segments.

Comment: Sirko, I seperated it, but again its not showing the legend,In console, its show the first value only and not on the front

Comment: @user12552117 can you prepare a small fiddle to show the rest of your code?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-joe1qh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @user12552117 sry, but stackblitz seems to have problems in all my browsers, so I can't have a look at the resulting HTML code.

Comment: I just add the code in fiddle, but its not running, atleast you get the code. [link](https://jsfiddle.net/jzv4up5k/1/)

Comment: That's only of limited use, sry. Check in the DOM structure, if all the `<text>` elements are inserted. Then you could check their coordinates. My guess is, that they are just rendered outside of your viewbox.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204943/discussion-between-user12552117-and-sirko).